# Find group $G$ and action of $G$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\mathbb{R}^2 / G \approx M \setminus \partial M$, open Mobius strip

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-actions, quotient-spaces

I want to find a group $G$ and an action of $G$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\mathbb{R}^2 / G \approx M \setminus \partial M$, where $M$ is the Mobious strip, and $\partial M$ is its boundary, a circle.

Some thoughts: when $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^2$, with translation, we get a torus. Also, if we act with $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ on the torus $S^{1} \times S^{1}$ by $m \times (z_{1}, z_{2}) = (z_{2}, z_{1})$ if $m=1$ and $(z_{1}, z_{2})$ if $m=0$, then we get a Mobius strip. So I thought maybe acting on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ would be a good idea, by making each group ($\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$) act accordingly. However, this action does not produce the desired results. Is there a better one that does?

Comment: That gives something compact. You want something noncompact. Try to think of an appropriate $\Bbb Z$ action (remember that $S^1 \times (-1,1)$ is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$ modulo $(x,y) \sim (x+1,y)$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you allow me to consider the open Mobius strip as the nontrivial fiber bundle of the circle $S^1$ with fiber $\mathbb{R}$, having one twist, then I can give one such group $G$.  Let $G:=\mathbb{Z}$.  The action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is given by $$n\cdot (x,y):=(x+n,(-1)^{n}y)$$
for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: This works for the quotient definition as well, $I^2/\sim$ where $(x,0) \sim (-x,1)$. Beyond these two I can't really think of a sensible definition